# When launching Appium on Android I get following error:

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: >Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more >details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing >the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.iserve.UChatPay' >application. Visit >https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running->appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original error: >'com.iserve.UChatPay.chat.activity.SplashScreenChat' or >'com.iserve.UChatPay.com.iserve.UChatPay.chat.activity.SplashScreenChat' never >started. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing->running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting

My Code :

[Please check image for code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fODiK.png)
}

Comment: I think your launchable activity name needs to be checked if it is correct or not.Also shared desired caps you are passing to create session.

Comment: @AmitJain I cross check and my Launchable avtivity is correct but still facing the same issue

Comment: If you include the code directly in your question (rather than using an image link), people are more likely to help out and the question will still be of use to people in the future if the link stops working.

Comment: @AmitJain after launching Launchable activity app getting open then we have some permission windows then after it will show this Error message.

Answer (score 0):

The error seem to indicate a wrong launch activity . Have you try abd shell to check the activity when it launch?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure only one instance of `appium` server is running on your machine. 
Close all the `appium` server before starting new session.